# CCS3 transition and jQuery toggleClass overflow:hidden doesnt work

Tags: jquery, css-transitions, toggleclass

I am trying to make a menu that slides in from the left, and pushes everything else 70% off canvas. I also want to remove the scroll when this action applies.

If I use jQuery to toggleClass on the wrapping container with overflow:hidden, the css transision effect does not work (except in IE10, where it actually works).

Here is a very simple example: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6gGmq/)

```
$('button').click(function () {
    $('#wrapper').toggleClass('hidden');
    $('#test').toggleClass('test');
    return false;
});

.hidden {
    overflow:hidden;
}
#test {
    position: absolute;
    left:-50px;
    transition: left 1s;
}
#test.test {
    left:100px;
}
```

It works if I remove the `$('#wrapper').toggleClass('hidden');` line.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Which versions of the other browsers are you using? Chrome only unprefixed `transition` in Chrome v26 so you need to use `-webkit-transition: left 1s;` in previous browser versions. Similarly, Firefox v16 was the first to support the unprefixed property.

Comment: Im using the latest versions on all browsers. This was just a simple example. The transision works if I remove the $('#wrapper').toggleClass('hidden'); so its not the prefix.

Comment: Ah ok, so do you want the element that transitions to push _everything_ else on the page left when it moves in?

Comment: Yeah, but all that is already taken care off. I just want to remove the scroll. Everything works fine if I have overflow:hidden on as default, but thats not what I want. I want to be able to add the overflow:hidden on the parent div when the button is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

You should add display:none instead of visibility

```
.hidden {
    display:none
}
```